# Is there a way to embed text on a limited page?

Tags: html, css, embed

The web page I am putting together has a character limit of 10,000, which is definitely not enough for me.

The page I am editing on has it's tabs divided with div ID. On the different tabs, all of the writing I have done takes up 80% of my character limit and I want to know if there is a website (something like Pastebin) where I can type all of the information I need on my tabs and embed the text into the Div ID pages. This would save a TREMENDOUS amount of characters I can use to continue coding.

If I can do this with Pastebin, could someone tell me how? I cannot use the embed option on the Pastebin website since it doesn't appear to work.

```
<script src=""></script>
```

Script src also wouldn't work since I am not embedding any code from the Pastebin file, it's just text. It's very important that I get this done... I'm stumped...

Comment: Ca you use iFrame's?

Comment: Could you give us an example of your webpage?

Comment: Nevermind, iframe works. You're a lifesaver, I'm surprised iframe didn't pop into my head. Only problem with it though is that the text doesn't follow the code I made for the text to appear as. For an example, if I make a h1 { for the text on the page to look like, say I choose Calibri, the text isn't in Calibri once I embed it with iframe. I think I can live with it though, I can just put that code onto the pastebin file anyway. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I posted it as answer.

Comment: I will look up a better solution for you, one sec.

Comment: I have posted a new answer,  using jQuery and AJAX to load text from an external file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery to make an AJAX request to the file.txt, and the result text will be placed inside the selected element.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="content">
    <p>Content loading...</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        context: this,
        dataType : "text",
        url : "file.txt",
        success : function(results) {
            $("#content").html(results);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```